# Pruning and keeping disk usage low

Tags: stellar-core, testnet

Does the Stellar network have the concept of pruning? If so, how do I go about configuring it?

I am running a node for development purposes but don't want the database and disk usage to become larger than a couple of gigs. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are looking for the [`/maintenance`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html#http-commands) HTTP command. It cleans unnecessary Stellar Core history, including XDR buckets stored on disk and records in the database.

If you plan to use Horizon in conjunction with Core node, you will only have access to the recent Stellar history, as a complete history archive requires a fully-synced Horizon node (currently more than 50 GB for public network).

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Could you elaborate a little more about it? Is it taking old ledgers and simply deleting them? Or is it transferring those ledger data to an archive? When I run the `/maintenance` command on a node connecting to the test network, I get `[default INFO] No work performed`.

Comment: Probably you have `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false` config parameter set. The `/maintenance` commands removes stale ledgers retaining only last `CATCHUP_RECENT` ledgers and performs `/buckets` dir cleanup.  You can configure automatic maintenance task runner using `AUTOMATIC_MAINTENANCE_PERIOD` and `AUTOMATIC_MAINTENANCE_COUNT` config params.

Comment: I just tried it both on nodes with `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false` and `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true` without touching `CATCHUP_RECENT`. Both still produces the same result.

Comment: Set `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false` and just wait for some time. The `/maintenance` command only schedules a maintenance job. When I run `/maintenance` on my node there were no changes for quite some time. I even restarted the service a few times. And then, two hours later, it started to delete records from the database in  huge batches. Don't know the internal mechanics of the process, so can't tell exactly how the maintenance is scheduled.