# Stop Horizon/Stellar node growing disk usage

Tags: stellar-core

I'm trying to find a way to keep Stellar disk usage in check. I only care about the last 24 hours or so of transactions and don't want to over-provision the instance

I started a docker container using the quick start

```
docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/home/ec2-user/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --pubnet
```

and updated `~/stellar/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg`, adding these lines

```
AUTOMATIC_MAINTENANCE_PERIOD=60
AUTOMATIC_MAINTENANCE_COUNT=500
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false
```

which after reading [this question](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/1394/2323) leads me to believe it will constrain the disk, yet the disk usage of my 30GB disk continues to climb until it consumes 100%.

[image: disk usage]

The reset to 25% usage is after I kill the container and delete `~/stellar`

I've also tried

```
docker exec 6 stellar-core http-command maintenance
```

but nothing good happens with disk, it just reports `No work performed`

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe postgres is not freeing the space? Not a postgres expert but isn't there a cleanup/maintenance command, too? Also do you have a cursor set `curl localhost:11626/getcursor`? It's a common set up to have a horizon cursor, in this case core will not free the resources that horizon (or whatever other app with cursor) didn't fetch yet.

Comment: It appears there is a cursor (I think). On a newly reset quickstart container: `{"cursors":[{"cursor":24563082,"id":"HORIZON"}]}`. Not sure whether that is expected or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stellar-core maintenance doesn't actually free disc space. Disc space is freed by [postgres's vacuum daemon](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/autovacuum.php) (which clears data that's been logically deleted). perhaps your PG isnt running periodical vacuum? you can also issue manual, 'vacuum full' to clear the space, but you'll need to stop the core, first.

Comment: Ah! The default image does have settings autovacuum commented out. Have enabled `track_counts = on` and `autovacuum = on`. Will report back

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work and disk went to 100% again. Assuming vacuum can't work with full disk so will let it climb to 50% and then see if I can manually force a postgres vacuum

Comment: Tried a direct command like this `docker exec --interactive 36 psql -d core -U stellar -W` - it prompts for a password which is accepted (it doesn't give an auth fail error) but then the cursor goes to the next line and nothing happens. Manual VACUUM attempt defeated.

Comment: this isnt how you issue manual vacuum. you need to connec to the db, which is likely postgres) and issue "vaccum full;" connecting to the  db is often done with a client like psql. which db are you running?

Comment: yes - using postgres which comes from the stellar quick start stack but it is inside the docker container, hence was trying to execute `psql` via docker exec. Got this command to work in the today: `docker exec -it dc vacuumdb --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=core --username=stellar --analyze --verbose --full` but disk consumption was unchanged afterward